# My car engine turns off while driving

Tags: engine, fuel-system

I have Tata Tiago 2017. I am facing a problem specially in summer. When I drive more than 100 km car engine automatically turn off after 1-2 hickups. If you try to start again it works but again after some kms it turns off. Tried to visit the vehicle to mechanic but when I reached there it worked fine almost for 20 km while test drive so problem couldn't identify. But in my recent trip when I faced this problem unknowingly i open the valve of fuel tak as well. At that time I realised that a pressure has been released. So I followed the same practice at every 50 km then I didn't face this issue again because every time pressure released from fuel tank. Can you plz suggest what is the issue in my car because many times I have visited service center but they are unable to identify problem.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find any information about your particular make and model of car, so this is going to be more general than I like.

There is a ventilation valve in the fuel system to equalize air pressure in the fuel tank, if it that valve fails or the vent system gets clogged then suction is created as your fuel pump pushes fuel out of the tank to the engine. Eventually the suction becomes too much for the pump to overcome, your fuel pressure drops and your engine stalls. Opening the gas cap lets air in and is a workable temporary solution, it's probably good to do it more often than 50km though just to be sure.

As for getting it fixed, cars used to have this valve built into the fuel cap, but most cars have a separate valve with a breather tube integrated into the filler line. That's probably where your problem lies.